# Where to put extra directives for IPv4 + IPv6 enabled interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: debian, configuration, linux-networking

To create a bridge over a geneve tunnel my interface configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` needs following "extra" directives:

```
        bridge_ports fancytun
        bridge_stp on

        pre-up ip link add dev fancytun type geneve remote 1.2.3.4 vni 1234
        pre-up ip link set dev fancytun up
        post-down ip link set dev fancytun down
        post-down ip link del dev fancytun
```

Where should I put those directives to not cause any problems during networking startup/shutdown?
I'm thinking - for example - of invalid states because bridge and up/down scripts were configured for IPv4, but IPv6 gets started first; or vice versa.
Is the position of the directives relevant at all?

For completeness here is the bridge-interface configuration which may be applied to the tunnel+bridge:

```
auto fancybr0
iface fancybr0 inet static
        address  192.168.0.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        ## may the bridge_ + up/down directives appear here?

iface fancybr0 inet6 static
        address  1::2:3
        netmask  112
        ## may the bridge_ + up/down directives appear here?
```